# Find and replace a specific text in a word document (.doc) using Visual Basic 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition, my goal is to read an entire .doc file and replace a specific word with a new one and print the newly edited .doc when you press a command button.

I've tried the codes in this forum but i think it only work on .txt - refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129288/find-and-replace-text-in-a-txt-document-using-visual-basic/10129515#10129515?newreg=dae30a49667f4d6089bf52fd0c37f356).

and I don't see anything that can help me [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb157880.aspx).

Comment: have you considered simple VBA code? you don't need VB.NET for that and it could be rather easy to do so (with macro recorder which could be a good starting point for you).

Comment: @KazJaw Actually it is needed to be run on visual basic 2010 Express Edition. I am not familiar with VBA or macro recorder. According to some forums that i browse, Express Edition doesn't support macro recorder. is there any alternative for this? one i can use on express edition.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all occurances...

```
Sub FindAndReplace(findText, replaceText)
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = findText
            .Replacement.Text = replaceText
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End Sub
```