# Visual Basic Replacing Part Of A Text File

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

[Referencing this answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10129515/1925536) I'm wondering how I can expand this code to act as searching for a place holder and modifying the text after it:

```
Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt").Replace("Number Remaining: [oldvalue]", "Number Remaining: [newvalue]")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\test2.txt", fileReader, False)
```

Where `oldvalue` is the number remaining before the edit (which I don't always know, so can't include it in the search) and `newvalue` is a value that is calculated elsewhere in the code.

The values are both `Double` types.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression to match a simple number.

First, add `System.Text.RegularExpressions` to your imports at the top of the file.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
Dim newValue As Double = 12.34 'or whatever
Dim fileText As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
fileText = Regex.Replace(fileText,
                         "Number Remaining: [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?", 
                         string.Format("Number Remaining: {0}", newValue))
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\test2.txt", fileText, False)
```

The regex `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` means a digit (`[0-9]`), 1 or more times (`+`), optionally (`?`) followed by a dot (`\.`) and more digits.

If your number might be formatted differently, you will have to adjust the regex to suit.

Comment: I get an error on the line `Regex.Replace(` saying that `Regex` is not declared

Comment: Add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` to the top of your file