# Find and replace a range of text from a text box

Tags: vb.net

Into a **Visual Basic** project I am trying to **replace** a part of **URL** coming from a **text box**. For example, I have this `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/blahblahblah/s912-Ic42/blahblahblah.jpg` URL into `TextBox1` and I want to replace the part `/s912-` with `/s1600-`.

I did it by doing something like this: `Dim url = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "/s912-", "/s1600-")`. But, this URL isn't the same every time. The part `/s912-` coould be `/s800-` for example. So my next though is to use an asterik: `Dim url = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "/s*-", "/s1600-")`. Of course it doesn'r work! So I need help with the syntax or a better idea.

Comment: have you heard of regular expressions? regex101.com

Comment: Use a [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28hw3sce(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Yes I found this using google but I can't understand the syntax. Maybe cause my head is ready to blowup right now. Can I have an example for my case please?

Comment: I added another answer for you, an experiment. It shows you a different method and performance implications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be used to search/replace using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

```
Dim input = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/blahblahblah/s912-Ic42/blahblahblah.jpg"
Dim output = Regex.Replace(input, "/s\d+-", "/s1600-")
```

`output` is:

> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/blahblahblah/s1600-Ic42/blahblahblah.jpg

Comment: You are 99% correct... I should also add this `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` at the top of my code. Thank you very much!!! :)

Comment: The pattern given by T.S. matches either `s` or `S`, which may or may not be important to you.  You could use their pattern in the above `Replace` call if needed.

Comment: Yea, I added "S". Who knows, URL is not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim url As String = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/blahblahblah/s912-Ic42/blahblahblah.jpg"
Dim pattern As String = "\/[sS][0-9]+-"
Dim newPart As String = "/s1600-"
Dim newUrl As String

Dim m as Match = regex.Match(url, pattern)
If m.Success Then
    Dim curr as String = url.Substring(m.Index, m.Length)
    newUrl = url.Replace(curr, newPart)
End If

' Test
Console.WriteLine(newUrl)
```

Result:

> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/blahblahblah/s1600-Ic42/blahblahblah.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this experiment. I want to show you another method and why `Regex` can be sometimes detrimental. Although, I am NOT saying that in your case you shouldn't use static call of Regex.

```
Dim url As String = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/blahblahblah/s912-Ic42/blahblahblah.jpg"

Dim sw As new System.Diagnostics.stopwatch()
sw.Start()

' Lets see how code can do without regex
Dim joined As String

For t as Integer = 1 to 5000
    Dim pos as Integer

    Dim results() As String = url.Split("/".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None)
    For i As Integer = 0 To results.Length - 1
        If results(i).Length > 1 AndAlso results(i).StartsWith("s", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            pos = results(i).IndexOf("-", 1)
            If pos > 1 Then ' we care only of "s+[0-9]"
                results(i) = results(i).Replace(results(i).Substring(0, pos), "/s1600-")
            End If
        End If
    Next
    joined = String.Join("/",  results, 0, results.Length)
Next

sw.Stop()
Console.WriteLine("Non-Regex: " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds & " ms. Output: " & joined)

' New Test  
sw.reset()  

' Lets see how nice shared regex call really is
Dim output As String
sw.Start()
For t As Integer = 1 to 5000
    output = Regex.Replace(url, "\/s\d+-", "/s1600-")
Next

sw.Stop()

Console.WriteLine("Regex Static: " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds & " ms. Output: " & output)

sw.Reset()
Dim output2 As String
sw.Start()

Dim rx As New Regex("\/s\d+-")
For t As Integer = 1 To 5000
    output2 = rx.Replace(url, "/s1600-")
Next

sw.Stop()

Console.WriteLine("Regex Instance: " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds & " ms. Output: " & output2)
```

Results samplings:

> Non-Regex: 14 ms.
>   Regex Static: 15 ms.
>   Regex Instance: 9 ms.
>   Non-Regex: 13 ms.
>   Regex Static: 14 ms.
>   Regex Instance: 8 ms.
>   Non-Regex: 13 ms.
>   Regex Static: 14 ms.
>   Regex Instance: 8 ms.
>   Non-Regex: 15 ms.
>   Regex Static: 14 ms.
>   Regex Instance: 8 ms.
>   Non-Regex: 13 ms.
>   Regex Static: 16 ms.
>   Regex Instance: 8 ms.

What I see is calling Regex instance methods work better. Non-regex method will perform worse with url getting longer. But, same will go for regex. I made url longer with more parts, and started to get

> Non-Regex: 33 ms.
>   Regex Static: 26 ms.
>   Regex Instance: 21 ms.

So, lets say, if your url will get longer but number of path parts will remain same, regex will lose some performance, and non-regex method will lose some too but not as much. But if you add parts, non-regex will really deteriorate.

It is in your hands to **optimize your code** for your specific usage. Do not assume that using one method over another is always right thing to do.