# VB - Find Replace on File

Tags: vb.net, replace, sed

i have the following file :

```
/home/InputDirectory/DHddmmyy.txt
/home/InputDirectory2/DHddmmyy.txt
/home/InputDirectory3/DHddmmyy.txt
```

I would like to do the "Sed" equivalent from VB, so i dont have to call a cygwin sed to do this job, the end result should be :

```
/home/InputDirectory/DH250816.txt
/home/InputDirectory2/DH250816.txt
/home/InputDirectory3/DH250816.txt
```

The variable will be passed as a parameter into the script. Really inexperienced with anything VB, so any help would be greatly appreciated. The only thing close i ve found is this :

```
Dim TestString As String = "Shopping List"
' Returns "Shipping List".
Dim aString As String = Replace(TestString, "o", "i")
```

but how do i iterate over each line to perform that? Isnt there a way to do this for every line of a file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129288/find-and-replace-text-in-a-txt-document-using-visual-basic

Comment: VB.NET is not the same as VBA. Choose your language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.
Here I have created a function which replaces "ddmmyy" with current date (in the same format)

```
Function FormatFileName(sFileName As String) As String
    Dim sReturnValue As String

    sReturnValue = Replace(sFileName, "ddmmyy", Format(Now(), "ddmmyy"), , ,   vbTextCompare)

    FormatFileName = sReturnValue
End Function
```

You may test the code by using below test procedure

```
Sub Process()
    Dim sOutputFileName As String

    sOutputFileName = FormatFileName("/home/InputDirectory/DHddmmyy.txt")
    Debug.Print sOutputFileName

    sOutputFileName = FormatFileName("/home/InputDirectory2/DHddmmyy.txt")
    Debug.Print sOutputFileName

    sOutputFileName = FormatFileName("/home/InputDirectory3/DHddmmyy.txt")
    Debug.Print sOutputFileName

End Sub
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: If i wanted to manually input a date? Say in a YYMMDD format? Thank you!!!

Comment: then pass the date as a parameter/argument in the function

    Function FormatFileName(sFileName As String, dtDate As Date) As String
        Dim sReturnValue As String

        sReturnValue = Replace(sFileName, "ddmmyy", Format(dtDate, "ddmmyy"), , ,   vbTextCompare)

        FormatFileName = sReturnValue
    End Function

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can just replace all at once

```
Dim text = File.ReadAllText("C:\1.txt")
text = text.Replace("ddmmyy", Now.ToString("ddMMyy")) 
File.WriteAllText("C:\1.txt", text)
```